# Framework error Mapbox using Cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I am currently building an app which needs MapboxGL. The app runs fine in the simulator, however, when I try to run it on a physical device it gives me certain framework errors. One of the errors which is coming back is:

```
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/otool: 
can't open file: /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Appname-
dairmpiobesmnjfpevvylizbwkct/Build/Products/Debug-
iphoneos/Appname.app/Frameworks/MapboxGL.framework/MapboxGL 
(No such file or directory)
```

I have removed the entire pod references and added these pods again to the project, this unfortunately did not resolve my problem.
I have created a new project, initializing Pods with it and build/run it again, but the error keeps coming back instantly.
I am using Xcode 7 beta 5 with the SWIFT language.
Nothing has been found by my Google searches and I hope someone could resolve this issue.

My pod file:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'

pod 'MapboxGL'

use_frameworks!
```

Comment: It looks like you're using Xcode 7 betas. You might want to follow these tickets to see if they help and to make sure you are using the latest `master` with these fixes: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues?utf8=✓&q=label%3Aprerelease-os+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to set the 'enable bitcode' field in my build options to false!